# event calling class method which calls another class method (same instance) within hitch

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to create a class that handles drawing shapes.  It is from an example from ArcGIS API for JS (Esri)
[https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=toolbar_draw][1]

In index.html I have a script tag that holds my javascript.  It creates the MyMultiSelect instance (from MyMultiSelect.js).  In the MyMultiSelect js file, I am having to use the global instance 'myMs' to set the event handler for:

`'this.toolbar.on("draw-end", this.myMs.addToMap)'  and 
  this.toolbar.on("draw-end", this.myMs.activateTool)'.`

Both addToMap and activateTool are methods/functions of the MyMultiSelect.js class.  When I used

`this.activateToMap and 
this.activateTool` (through debugger),

the methods were undefined.  It seems when using hitch it only sees the variables, not the methods.  What am I doing wrong - I really can't use the global 'myMs', I did it for testing.   Thanks!

Any help would be great!

```
index.html (script tag)
...
    "dojo/domReady!"
function(Map, Draw, Graphic,
                 SimpleMarkerSymbol, 
                 SimpleLineSymbol, 
                 SimpleFillSymbol,
                 parser, 
                 registry,
                 ext,
                 sr,
                 MyMultiSelect,
        ) { 
            parser.parse(); 

            let lastExtent;
            let defaultExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent({
                xmin: -10919311.41681004,
                ymin: 3612806.5850415034,
                xmax: -10625793.228194851,
                ymax: 3748100.125106317,
                "spatialReference": {"wkid":3857}
            });                     


            map = new esri.Map("map", {
                extent: ((lastExtent) ? lastExtent : defaultExtent),
                basemap: "streets",
                infoWindow: new esri.dijit.Popup({}, dojo.create("div")),
                sliderPosition: "top-right",
                logo: false,
                fadeOnZoom: true,
                force3DTransforms: true,
                // navigationMode: "css-transforms",
                optimizePanAnimation: true,
                //lods: gs.conf.lods,
            });

            // map.on("click", addPoint);

            // function addPoint(evt) {
            //  var latitude = evt.mapPoint.getLatitude();
            //  map.infoWindow.setTitle("Check");
            //  map.infoWindow.setContent("HI");
            //  map.infoWindow.show(evt.mapPoint);
            // }

            myMs = new MyMultiSelect(map);
            // map.on("load", createToolbar);
            map.on("load", myMs.createToolbar);

MyMultiSelect.js
...
    "dojo/domReady!"
],
function (Map, Draw, Graphic,
          SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol,
          parser, registry, declare, lang) {

    return declare(null, {

        constructor: function(map) {
            this.map = map;
            this.toolbar = null;
            console.log("HI");
        },

        createToolbar: lang.hitch(this, function() {
            this.toolbar = new Draw(this.map);
            this.toolbar.on("draw-end", this.myMs.addToMap);

            registry.forEach(function(d) {
                // d is a reference to a dijit
                // could be a layout container or a button
                if ( d.declaredClass === "dijit.form.Button" ) {
                    d.on("click", this.myMs.activateTool);
                }
            });
        }),

        addToMap: lang.hitch(this, function(evt){
            let symbol;
            this.toolbar.deactivate();
            this.map.showZoomSlider();
            switch (evt.geometry.type) {
              case "point":
              case "multipoint":
                symbol = new SimpleMarkerSymbol();
                break;
              case "polyline":
                symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
                break;
              default:
                symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
                break;
            }
            var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol);
            this.map.graphics.add(graphic);
        }),

        activateTool: lang.hitch(this, function(evt) {
            let btn = dijit.registry.byId('pt');
            var tool = btn.label.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
            this.toolbar.activate(Draw[tool]);
            this.map.hideZoomSlider();
        }),
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you know about `super`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Comment: Yes - I know about super.  That is if I want to call a method from a parent class (inheritance).  The method 'this.addToMap' is defined in the class that I'm trying to call.   I should have made it clear the 'myMs' is an instance of the class that is instantiated in the main script (main.js) that I did not show.

Answer (score 0):

you should type `this.addToMap` as you are calling that function inside the Class definition. as you do with `this.map`

Eventually, you should define the variables `map` and `toolbar` before the constructor :

```
map: null,
toolbar: null,

constructor: ...
```

Comment: I did use 'this.addToMap'.  This did not work.  The 'this.myMs.addToMap' works.  I should have made it clear the 'myMs' is an instance of the class that is instantiated in the main script (main.js) that I did not show.

Comment: Sorry - should have been more clear. I have updated my code above. In index.html I have a script tag that holds my javascript. It creates the MyMultiSelect instance (from MyMultiSelect.js).  I used the debugger to see what the problem was for 'this.activateTool'.  It was undefined.  Same with other method